# Error in R: mutate( ) must be size 4 or 1, not 0

Tags: r, dplyr, error-handling

My data:

```
data_control <-  structure(list(group = c("control", "control", "control", "control" ), cycle = c(0, 1, 2, 3), non_obese_prob = c(1, -0.0133333333333334, 0.00017777777777778, -0.00000237037037037042), obese_prob = c(0, 1.01333333333333, 0.999822222222222, 1.00000237037037)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

data_qaly <- structure(list(cycle = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3), qaly = c(0.879173868649325, 0.876535027508255, 0.876535027508255, 0.876535027508255, 0.729214080532041, 0.73572153807131, 0.73572153807131, 0.73572153807131), state = c("non_obese", "non_obese", "non_obese", "non_obese", "obese", "obese", "obese", "obese")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
data_control <- data_control %>% 
                mutate(qaly_non_obese = data_qaly$qaly[data_qaly$state == "non-obese"]) %>%
                mutate(qaly_obese = data_qaly$qaly[data_qaly$state == "obese"])
```

Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `qaly_non_obese`.
ℹ `qaly_non_obese = data_qaly$qaly[data_qaly$state == "non-obese"]`.
ℹ `qaly_non_obese` must be size 4 or 1, not 0.

Comment: Could you provide some data. `dput(data_control)` and\or `dput(data_qaly)`

Comment: dput(data_control): 

structure(list(group = c("control", "control", "control", "control"
), cycle = c(0, 1, 2, 3), non_obese_prob = c(1, -0.0133333333333334, 
0.00017777777777778, -0.00000237037037037042), obese_prob = c(0, 
1.01333333333333, 0.999822222222222, 1.00000237037037)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: dput(data_qaly):

structure(list(cycle = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3), qaly = c(0.879173868649325, 
0.876535027508255, 0.876535027508255, 0.876535027508255, 0.729214080532041, 
0.73572153807131, 0.73572153807131, 0.73572153807131), state = c("non_obese", 
"non_obese", "non_obese", "non_obese", "obese", "obese", "obese", 
"obese")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need a `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(data_control, data_qaly, by="cycle")
```

```
    group cycle non_obese_prob obese_prob      qaly     state
1 control     0   1.000000e+00  0.0000000 0.8791739 non_obese
2 control     0   1.000000e+00  0.0000000 0.7292141     obese
3 control     1  -1.333333e-02  1.0133333 0.8765350 non_obese
4 control     1  -1.333333e-02  1.0133333 0.7357215     obese
5 control     2   1.777778e-04  0.9998222 0.8765350 non_obese
6 control     2   1.777778e-04  0.9998222 0.7357215     obese
7 control     3  -2.370370e-06  1.0000024 0.8765350 non_obese
8 control     3  -2.370370e-06  1.0000024 0.7357215     obese
```